# Voice Artists and where to find the good ones

Tags: voice-over, video-games

I'm starting pre production on a rather ambitious self funded game project. 
And almost sadly, this will be beyond the stage of myself and friends being roped in to do the voices.

I am curious as to resources people here are aware of for hiring voice talent? Both U.K local and of course remote. 
Many attempts to search this myself has brought up kitchenware style advert voice overs. Not the style of V.O you would expect for a game.

This ie me really just putting the feelers out so I can start to time and resource budget, so any help, is amazing help. : )

Thanks again guys

Comment: Here's one source, where you can post what you're looking for.: http://my.voiceacting.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Besides a casting agent, you could check out http://voiceactingalliance.com/ if you are on a tight budget. If you have the time to set up an audition and weed through the bad submissions (most of the voice actors there are not very experience and might not have very good equipment), it's not unlikely that you will find someone talented who is willing to work on an original project for a relatively low price, or even for free for their portfolio.

I don't have a very good point of reference, as I have never needed to go to a casting agent, but I have found several talented amateurs voice actors there for different projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have some voice actors I'm working with, if you're interested. Their voices are really suitable for video games. Shoot me an email at alchemyaudiodesign@gmail.com if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a casting agent - in the UK we have used [SideUK](http://www.side.com/) - casting is just one aspect of their work as they also can do all the recording and localization too. If you are looking for something lower budget I have also used acting students from the local theatre school. If you have time to audition a few people and are well prepared you might find gold :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the list of English Voice talent agencies listed below: If you need bilingual voiceovers check out amadorbilingualvoiceovers.com.  You can also email Rosi and ask her for talent recommendations.  Rosi Amador is a partner instructor at Edge Studios in NY for voiceover coaching and talent directory.  Definitely plugged in.

Also check out:

www.cybersoundmusic.com |
http://www.ariatalent.com/search/index.cfm |
Allstarvoices.com  |
www.edgestudio.com/  |

I also have done voiceover work starting in 2000 at Clear Channel Communications.
Some Demos: 
http://allstarvoices.com/profile/JoanBishop  |
http://audiorichter.bandcamp.com/album/voiceovers-production

You can also check out voiceover universe, Voices.com, voices123.com

Comment: Thanks to everyone so far, looks like I'll be planning a few email this week ;)
Its been a great worry of mine for this project as I know the V.O is either going to make it or break it. : )